# Knockoutjs: filling array property in model with jQuery on document ready

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I have the following code on jsFiddel, a simplified version of my code I'm using in my project.

http://jsfiddle.net/wUp24/2/

I am trying to preload my categories from the server like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var mv = new configuratorPublicModelView();
  ko.applyBindings(mv);
  mv.loadFunctions("", 1);
});
```

When I loop through the categories, you can see that they are loaded, but knockout doesn't do anything.

What is wrong?

**Edit**
I think it has something to do with the way I apply the binding. When I do the following:

```
  ko.applyBindings(new configuratorPublicModelView());
```

I can display a test observable, the other way it won't display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add new items into the observable array like so:

```
self.configuratorPublic().searchCategories.push("cat1");
```

Instead of:

```
self.configuratorPublic().searchCategories().push("cat1");
```

See here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/badsyntax/wUp24/3/